# Matrix associativity

Tags: linear-algebra

Matrix multiplication is associative.
However, I am confused by the following issue. Consider the following matrices and vectors:
$$W=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1&2&3\\
4&5&6\\
7&8&9
\end{array}\right), 
D=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1&0&0\\
0&2&0\\
0&0&3
\end{array}\right), 
v= \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
4\\
5\\
6
\end{array}\right).$$
Holds that $(Wv)D\neq W(vD)$. In fact,
$$(Wv)D= \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
78\\
174\\
270
\end{array}\right)\qquad W(vD)= \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
32\\
154\\
366
\end{array}\right).$$
Why do I get this result?

Thank you

Comment: By writing $v A$ for a vector $v$ and a matrix $A$, you actually mean $A v$. Then $(W v) D = D W v$ and $W (v D) = W D v$. You can expect that they are not the same.

Comment: Your $W$ and $D$ are $3\times 3$; $v$ is $3\times 1$. So $Wv$ is $3\times 1$, and cannot be multiplied by $D$. And $vD$ cannot be computed at all, because you cannot multiply a $3\times 1$ by a $3\times 3$. Neither of the two expressions is defined.

Comment: The matrix product $vD$ is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

By writing $v A$ for a vector $v$ and a matrix $A$, you actually mean $A v$. Then $(W v) D = D W v$ and $W (v D) = W D v$. You can expect that they are not the same.

As the comments pointed, **do not** write $v A$ for a column vector $v$. That doesn’t make sense, and will break the associativity.

You can, however, write $v A$ for a row vector $v$. You can see a column vector as an $n \times 1$ matrix, and a row vector as a $1 \times n$ matrix. Do not mix up the multiplication rules for column and row vectors. (In general, we use column vectors more often.)

Answer (score 1):

You can only multiply an $m\times n$ matrix by an $r\times s$ matrix when $n=r$, in which case you get an $m\times s$ matrix.

What associativity of matrix multiplication says is that if $A$ is $m\times n$, $B$ is $n\times p$, and $C$ is $p\times q$, then
$$(AB)C = A(BC),$$
with the result of both products being an $m\times q$ matrix.

You have two $3\times 3$ matrices $D$ and $W$, and a $3\times 1$ matrix $v$. While you can multiply both $D$ and $W$ by $v$, you cannot multiply $v$ by $D$, and you cannot multiply $Wv$ (which is a $3\times 1$ matrix) by $D$. So neither $(Wv)D$ nor $D(vW)$ are sensible expressions: in terms of size, you are trying to perform products of type
$$\Bigl( (3\times 3)\cdot(3\times1)\Bigr)\cdot (3\times 3) = (3\times 1)\cdot (3\times 3)$$
and
$$(3\times 3)\cdot\Bigl( (3\times 1)\cdot (3\times 3)\Bigr).$$
Neither one of those operations can be performed.

Comment: OMG, that's right! I made a blunder